# Substr get_post_meta data?

Tags: php, wordpress, substring

How can I limit the text to say 100 characters from the get_post_meta tag?

I need to grab the text in this style:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($relationship->ID, 'company_description', true ); ?>
```

This is how I would normally limit the text but I don't know how to combine it with the syntax above:

```
<?php echo substr($fields->company_description,0,100) . "..."; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most readable way:

```
$text = get_post_meta($relationship->ID, 'company_description', true);
echo substr($text, 0, 100) . "...";
```

Then of course, you could also nest the function calls, which probably sucks in terms of readability:

```
echo substr(get_post_meta($relationship->ID, 'company_description', true), 0, 100) . "...";
```

By the way: If `company_description` might contain raw HTML, you'll probably want to run `strip_tags()` over it before getting a substring – not stripping HTML would get you in trouble in the long run otherwise.

```
$text = strip_tags(get_post_meta($relationship->ID, 'company_description', true));
echo substr($text, 0, 100) . "...";
```